# Consulta sobre formula de Javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenos días hace unas 2 semanas comencé a estudiar javascript y estuve haciendo varios tipos de ejercicios, en su gran mayoría los llegue a comprender pero ayer me encontré con un ejercicio que requería lo siguiente para ser solucionado;

```
16  -->  1 + 6 = 7
942  -->  9 + 4 + 2 = 15  -->  1 + 5 = 6
132189  -->  1 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 8 + 9 = 24  -->  2 + 4 = 6
```

probe con un While pero sole llegaba a hacer la primera parte, por ejemplo en el caso del 942 el return daba 15 y se quedaba en eso, luego buscando me encontré con este metodo :

```
 function numero (n) {
     n = (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
      return n;
    }
```

La cual da el resultado correcto, pero me gustaría llegar a comprenderla, desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 11):

No se entiende bien lo que preguntas, pero voy a intentar adivinar.

El ejercicio que te pedían era un algoritmo para sumar las cifras de un número, y de nuevo del número resultante, etc. hasta llegar a una sola cifra. De ahí los ejemplos que suministras.

La solución que encontraste, en cambio, en vez de sumar las cifras de un número lo que hace es aplicar la fórmula `(n - 1) % 9 + 1`

Tu pregunta es ¿por qué esa fórmula arroja el mismo resultado que sumar las cifras del número hasta dejarlo en una sola?

### Respuesta

La respuesta es que la operación de sumar una y otra vez las cifras de un número hasta reducirlo sólo a una, es lo que se conoce como la [raiz digital del número](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root). Ocurre que esta raíz digital tiene la propiedad de ser igual al resto de la división por 9, excepto para el caso particular en que el resto sea 0 (en cuyo caso la raíz digital sale 9).

Sin entrar en la demostración, mira algunos ejemplos para convencerte:

- 18 (es múltiplo de 9). La raíz digital es 9, el resto de la divisón es 0
- 19 (no es múltiplo de 9). La raíz digital (suma de las cifras) es 1 (1+9=10, 1+0=1), lo que coincide con el resto de dividir por 9.
- 32 (no es múltiplo de 9). La raíz digital es 5, igual que el resto de la división por 9.

En general la propiedad se cumple siempre, salvo para el caso especial en que el número sea 0, pues en ese caso la raiz digital es 0 y no 9. Es el único caso en que la raíz digital puede salir cero.

Por tanto podríamos calcular la raíz digital con el siguiente algoritmo:

```
if (numero == 0) {
  // Este caso es especial y hay que tratarlo aparte
  raiz = 0;
} else {
  raiz = numero % 9;
  if (raiz==0) {
    raiz = 9;
  }
}
```

que básicamente pone en código lo mismo que dije más arriba en palabras.

La fórmula `(n-1)%9+1` es una forma ingeniosa de ahorrarse todos los `if` en la función anterior, ya que primero resta 1 al número, después calcula el resto de la división, y luego vuelve a sumar el 1 que había restado. Así se matan dos pájaros de un tiro. Si el número era 0, esto funcionará correctamente (por ser el resto -1), y también si el `n%9` era cero, se obtiene como resultado 9 en vez de 0 (ya que en ese caso `n-1` tendrá resto 8, y luego se le suma 1).

### ¿Y por qué la raiz digital equivale al resto de dividir por 9? ¿Y por qué 9?

El 9 es especial porque escribimos los números en base 10. Si los escribieramos en base 16, entonces la raíz digital sería igual el resto de dividir por 15 (o 15 si el resto es 0). En general, para la base `B` la raíz digital es igual al resto de dividir entre `B-1`.

¿Por qué?

Para hacer la demostración más comprensible la limitaré a números de 4 cifras y en base 10, pero fácilmente puedes ver que se generaliza para números con cualquier número de cifras y en cualquier base.

Cuando tenemos un número de 4 cifras, digamos el número `abcd` (siendo `a`, `b`, `c` y `d` las cifras individuales), ya que trabajamos en base 10 lo que estamos diciendo en realidad con el número `abcd` es que la cantidad representada es:

```
1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d
```

Ahora bien, 1000 puede ser escrito como 999+1, y análogamente con los demás. La cantidad por tanto es también esta:

```
(999+1)a + (99+1)b + (9+1)c + d
```

Operando un poco y reagrupando términos, lo anterior es igual a:

```
(999a + 99b + 9c) + (a+b+c+d)
```

Si divido lo anterior por 9, ya que el primer grupo es múltiplo de 9 por tener dentro todos esos nueves, el resto de la división me quedará simplemente `a+b+c+d`, es decir, la raiz digital del número.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta tan completa, ahora lo comprendo mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de la función, realizas los siguientes pasos:

1. Convertir el número a string
2. Convertir el string a un array
3. Iterar el array y hacer la sumatoria de cada elemento del array

Lo cual puedes lograr de la siguiente manera:

```js
function sumaNumero (numero) {
  numero = numero.toString(); // Convertir el número a string
  return [...numero].reduce((acumulado, valorActual) => { // Usar numero como string, como un array y 'reducirlo'
    return acumulado += Number(valorActual);
  }, 0);
}

const tests = [16, 942, 15, 132189, 24];

tests.forEach(numero => {
  console.log(`${numero} -> ${sumaNumero(numero)}`);
});
```

La forma de cómo iteres sobre el string puede variar, [existen muchas formas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22410812/7927192) para ello.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Ya se ha dado la solución usando recursividad pero me gustaría complementar con una alternativa no recursiva.

Para este problema cuando la suma entre dos numeros es `>= 10` podemos notar un patrón, cuando uno de los operandos es `9` seria equivalente a retornar el otro operando, digamos se le resta `0`, cuando uno de los operandos es `8` seria equivalente a retornar el otro operando menos `1`, siguiendo con esta lógica tendríamos que por cada numero seria equivalente a restar una contante

```
9 => 0
8 => 1
7 => 2
6 => 3
5 => 4
4 => 5
3 => 6
2 => 7
1 => 8
0 => no aplica ya que la suma nunca dará un resultado >= 10
```

Simplificando podemos notar que es la diferencia de `9 - digito`

Aplicando esto resultaría la siguiente solución

```
numero
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .reduce((suma, digito) => {
        digito = Number(digito);
        const sumaInterna = suma + digito;

        return sumaInterna < 10 ? sumaInterna : suma - (9 - digito);
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que el truco va por otro camino, creo que quieren que hagas una función recursiva que vaya sumando el numero hasta llegar a quedar con una cifra. A diferencia de la función que has pasado que te lleva al resultado final directamente.

Algo así:

```js
function sumNumber(num) {
  const result = num.toString().split('').reduce((acc, crr) => acc + Number(crr), 0);
  if (result.toString().length > 1) return sumNumber(result);
  return result;
};

console.log(sumNumber(16)); // -> 7
console.log(sumNumber(942)); // -> 6
console.log(sumNumber(132189)); // -> 6
```

y la solución exacta quizás seria esta:

```js
function sumNumber(num) {
  const numSplited = num.toString().split('');
  let result = `${num} --> ${numSplited.join(" + ")} = `;
  const sum = numSplited.reduce((acc, crr) => acc + Number(crr), 0);
  if (sum.toString().length > 1) return (result += sumNumber(sum));
  return result += sum;
};


console.log(sumNumber(16));
console.log(sumNumber(942));
console.log(sumNumber(132189));
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda!

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, lo probare